# How to find loop dependency?

Tags: c, dependencies

```
#pragma pipeline, max_latency = 5
for(int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
   //reuse distance >= 5  when N > 1
   z[i * N + 2] = foobar(z[i-1]));
}
```

I am reading a paper in the which it says that the above loop has a non-uniform dependency that is difficult to analyze, hence HLS (high level synthesis) tools make an assumption that the write in the current iteration is consumed in the next iteration. This prevents pipelining the loop. Thus user directives(pragmas) are used to bypass HLS analysis.

In the above code I don't understand the dependencies. For N > 1 all reads and writes are independent. Can someone explain the dependency?

Comment: Read tag-descriptions before adding.

Comment: The problem is not so much that there are dependencies, but that it's difficult *for a compiler* to analyze whether there are.

Comment: Typo in `for` loop.

Comment: you did not add enough information about the context in whichyou run the code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger   Thanks. So what does it mean when they say the reuse distance is 5. Doesn't the pragma allow 5 iterations to run parallel before assuming that there might be dependencies.